# How to pass parameter using parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to pass parameter of current element of select tag dynamically using may be this.(Something)
here i need id of  tag and  tag of my code which is passed on onchange event

```
 function ToggleDropDown(id1,id2)
 {/* Code */}


      controls += '<span class="ui-btn-text" id="globalSelect">' + options.data[0].GlobalFieldName + '</span>';          
      controls += '<select id="GlobalFieldName" onchange=ToggleDropDown("GlobalFieldName","globalSelect");>'; 
      jQuery.each(options.data, function (index) {
```

so How to pass parameter using this.***(something) so I can get ID of current div every time.
For example :

```
alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
```

Comment: that markup within js looks so ugly

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use `$(this)` to access the current element and then call `.parent()` to get the parent element.  I am not sure what you are asking, but this is how it works:

HTML:

```
<div class="theParent"><a href="#" class="theChild">Click me</a></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.theChild').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide(); // hides "theParent"
    $(this).parent().attr('class'); // logs "theParent" to the console
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5GuED/